# Operand type clash: image is incompatible with varchar(max)

Tags: sql, vb.net

I got the following error , when i am trying to insert data into the table and having the image type field.
Operand type clash: image is incompatible with varchar(max)

So any one help me out to solve this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your (cutdown) code please and table defs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Random guess: image is replaced by varbinary(max)

While we're on the subject...

- text would be varchar(max)
- ntext would be nvarchar(max)

Answer (score 0):

Even though you may specify the parameter names in your code, while preparing the execution the names will be ignored in the actual SQL expression and be placed one after another, so their meaning will depend on their position. 
Make sure you don't skip any optional parameters and organize them in exact order as they defined in the SQL procedure.